# What is the lifetime of coroutineScope in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

The Code A is from the project architecture samples at https://github.com/android/architecture-samples

1: I don't know if the function `activateTask(task: Task)` need to be wrapped with `runBlocking` just like Code B. I'm afraid that `activateTask(task: Task)` maybe not be run if the object of `DefaultTasksRepository` is destroyed quickly.

2: Normally I run coroutines in `ViewModel.viewModelScope`, I don't know whether the `ViewModel.viewModelScope` will be destroyed when I finish the app, and whether the coroutines running in `ViewModel.viewModelScope` will be destroyed too.  If so, I think it will be bad, some long time coroutines such as writing data to remote server will be cancel.

3: And more, the function `activateTask` in Code A is a coroutines function, it can invoke another coroutines function directly, so I think the Code A+ is correct, right?

**Code A**

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.coroutineScope
...

class DefaultTasksRepository(
    private val tasksRemoteDataSource: TasksDataSource,
    private val tasksLocalDataSource: TasksDataSource,
    private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO
) : TasksRepository {
   ...

   override suspend fun activateTask(task: Task) = withContext<Unit>(ioDispatcher) {
        coroutineScope {
            launch { tasksRemoteDataSource.activateTask(task) }
            launch { tasksLocalDataSource.activateTask(task) }
        }
    }

   override suspend fun clearCompletedTasks() {
        coroutineScope {
            launch { tasksRemoteDataSource.clearCompletedTasks() }
            launch { tasksLocalDataSource.clearCompletedTasks() }
        }
    }
   ...
}
```

**Code A+**

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.coroutineScope
...

class DefaultTasksRepository(
    private val tasksRemoteDataSource: TasksDataSource,
    private val tasksLocalDataSource: TasksDataSource,
    private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO
) : TasksRepository {
   ...

   override suspend fun activateTask(task: Task) = withContext<Unit>(ioDispatcher) {
        tasksRemoteDataSource.activateTask(task) 
        tasksLocalDataSource.activateTask(task)         
    }

   override suspend fun clearCompletedTasks() {            
        tasksRemoteDataSource.clearCompletedTasks() 
        tasksLocalDataSource.clearCompletedTasks()             
   }
   ...
}
```

**Code B**

```
fun main() = runBlocking { 
    launch { 
      delay(1000L)
      println("World!")
    }
    println("Hello,")
}
```

Comment: You're confused with coroutines and their components, i'd suggest you to read first-things-first about coroutines https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/coroutines-first-things-first-e6187bf3bb21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should not use runBlocking in any coroutine application, it blocks the thread.

   If you really want to make `activateTask` non-cancellable there is a factory implementation of [NonCancellable](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-non-cancellable.html) already in the stdlib

   And you should not use coroutineScope wrapper inside the withContext, as a newly created CoroutineScope along with a new job is already passed as receiver within `withContext`.

   Implement your activateTask like this:

```kotlin
override suspend fun activateTask(task: Task) = withContext<Unit>(ioDispatcher + NonCancellable) {
    launch { tasksRemoteDataSource.activateTask(task) }
    launch { tasksLocalDataSource.activateTask(task) }
}
```

In this way it will be called on the IODispatcher but will not be cancellable since the `Job` element of the resulting context does not provide functionality to cancel it.

2. ViewModelScope runs till your application is destroyed, more info and lifecycle chart is [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#lifecycle). If you want to run some very important tasks, then use other dispatchers.
3. Yes code A+ is completely correct

**PS:** You should not implement runBlocking in a coroutine application, its default implementation is just the event loop.

> runBlocking is the way to bridge synchronous and asynchronous code

Better implementation of main function should be:

```kotlin
suspend fun main() = coroutineScope {
    // code here
}
```

It runs on the CommonPool, and if it suspends another coroutine could reuse the same thread.

Comment: Thanks! What are different between Code A and Code A+ ? I think that Code A just like asynchronous, and Code A+ just like synchronal, right?

Comment: @HelloCW there is no difference in `activateTask` both runs the same, only thing is that the nested coroutineScope call just overrides the Job element in coroutineContext. On `clearCompletedTasks` the coroutineScope inherits the context from wherever it was called on and launches them in that context (concurrently if dispatcher of context support multi-threading environment), there is no reason to do that for very small tasks like clearing.